Google Sheets Script: getNextDataCell() Not Working
Recently some functions stopped working correctly in Script.
One is range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP) - commonly used to find the last Data cell in a column.  It appears the 'Direction.UP' is being ignored?
This function now fails, and returns "Last data row is: 1":
function import_GetLastRow() {
  const sheetName = 'HourlyData';
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  Logger.log('Sheet: ' + sheet.getName());

  const column = "A"; // The column you're checking
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); // Get the actual last row in the sheet
  const range = sheet.getRange(column + "3:" + column + lastRow); // Define the range from row 3 to the last row
  Logger.log('Range: ' + range.getA1Notation());

  try {
    // Traverse upwards in the column to find the last cell with data
    const lastDataCell = range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP);
    Logger.log(`Last data cell is in row: ${lastDataCell.getRow()}`);
        // "Last data row is: 1"
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(`Error: ${error.message}`);
  }
}


Perhaps, you need to use DOWN instead of UP

No, I'm trying to find the Last Data Row, not the first.
range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP) has been working fine for years.  GAS has an issue.

This could be fails in certain data distribution into the sheet. LastRow returns the position of the last row that has content, try getMaxRows that returns the current number of rows in the sheet, regardless of content and explore from that last cell.

@jpp most often scripts need to discover the last row that has content so that they can append data below. If that's what's needed, Sheet.getMaxRows() is not the right choice, because its result includes completely blank rows at the bottom. I'd actually suggest appendRows_() for that.

@doubleunary  Indeed, I use the methods of finding the last Data row for appending new rows.

@maxhugen if the use case is to append data to a sheet, use appendRows_().

An alternative to getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP) is to use a For loop, and for efficiency, start from the end of the range.  Logger correctly returned "Last data row is: 9204".
function import_GetLastRow() {
  const sheetName = 'HourlyData';
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const data = sheet.getRange('A3:A').getValues(); // Get all data in column A starting from row 3
  let lastDataRow = 2; // Start before row 3

  for (let i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {    // Start from the end
    if (data[i][0] !== "") {                      // Check if the cell is non-empty
      lastDataRow = i + 3;                        // Adjust for 0-based index and start row
      break;                                      // Exit loop as soon as we find the last non-empty cell
    }
  }
  Logger.log(`Last data row is: ${lastDataRow}`);
                                                  // "Last data row is: 9204"
}

[Edit] reported to Google.

Link your report for more traffic

Not concerned about my traffic - but feel free to link it to yourself,  if you think it's helpful to other GAS devs?

Use the getLastRow_() utility function, like this:
function import_GetLastRow() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('HourlyData');
  const lastDataRow = getLastRow_(sheet, 'A3:A');
  console.log(`lastDataRow: ${lastDataRow}`);
}

